# How to diagnose Spark job failures coming out of Kyro and LZF compression?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, deserialization, hadoop2

My spark job running on Hadoop cluster is failing many times with following error:

> com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: com.ning.compress.lzf.LZFException: Corrupt input data, block did not start with 2 byte signature ('ZV') followed by type byte, 2-byte length)

The job succeeds many times but fails also many times. It may fail few times and succeed next time for the same underlying data-set, spark config as well as Hadoop config.

Here's the stacktrace.

```
User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 659 in stage 8.0 failed 24 times, most recent failure: Lost task 659.23 in stage 8.0 (TID 3662, atl-hdp-061.afy.gbl): com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: com.ning.compress.lzf.LZFException: Corrupt input data, block did not start with 2 byte signature ('ZV') followed by type byte, 2-byte length)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.fill(Input.java:142)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.require(Input.java:155)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.readInt(Input.java:337)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:109)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClass(Kryo.java:610)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:721)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoDeserializationStream.readObject(KryoSerializer.scala:228)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.DeserializationStream.readKey(Serializer.scala:169)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.DeserializationStream$$anon$2.getNext(Serializer.scala:201)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.DeserializationStream$$anon$2.getNext(Serializer.scala:198)
at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:32)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap.insertAll(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:152)
at org.apache.spark.Aggregator.combineCombinersByKey(Aggregator.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.BlockStoreShuffleReader.read(BlockStoreShuffleReader.scala:91)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDD.compute(ShuffledRDD.scala:98)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD.compute(UnionRDD.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:69)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:268)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.ning.compress.lzf.LZFException: Corrupt input data, block did not start with 2 byte signature ('ZV') followed by type byte, 2-byte length)
at com.ning.compress.lzf.ChunkDecoder._reportCorruptHeader(ChunkDecoder.java:267)
at com.ning.compress.lzf.impl.UnsafeChunkDecoder.decodeChunk(UnsafeChunkDecoder.java:55)
at com.ning.compress.lzf.LZFInputStream.readyBuffer(LZFInputStream.java:363)
at com.ning.compress.lzf.LZFInputStream.read(LZFInputStream.java:193)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.fill(Input.java:140)
... 61 more
```

Comment: I am not sure there is sufficient detail here for readers to be able to help. I don't know this technology, but do you perhaps have some code you can show? Yes, if there is a stack trace you have not given, I would say it is better to include it, rather than waiting to be asked for it.

Comment: @halfer, I added the stacktrace. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: OK, can you look into why you get the `LZFException` then? Is this a file that is created? What creates it? Is that something your code does, or something in Spark or Hadoop?

Comment: Any insights from anybody here? Google search did not return any relevant leads. Spark (1.6.0) with Kyro serialization and LZF compression throws up this error, frequently. But finding it difficult to diagnose and rectify.

Comment: Am getting a similar compression related error when I change the compression.codec to lz4.reason:

    "java.io.IOException: Stream is corrupted"

So I am not sure if this is bug in the compression or Kryo Serialization or Spark

Comment: I and other engineers tried snappy/lz4/lzf. Each one of them gave some compression related error. So I don't think it is related to compression codec/library. We are testing to swap out kryo serialization for java serialization and see if that works.

Comment: Is it worth retagging this question as `java` or `scala` for greater visibility?